# Use express validator and custom validation on field node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I am using express validator for validation.
I wanted to check if the **name** is not empty and if it exists then remove the extra spaces between the string.

Using this below code only the second part of the validation works

```
  case 'name': {
  return [
    check('name', 'Name is required').not().isEmpty().trim().escape()
    .matches(/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/).withMessage('Name must be alphabetic.')
  
  ],(req,res,next) => {
    req.body.name = req.body.name.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    next();
  }
}
```

The above code gives this response which I don't want

```
//input
john    name  one 12

//output 
// it should give error Name must be alphabetic
john name one 12
```

How I achieve this using express validation and custom validation

Comment: instead of matches try with .custom e.x. custom((value, {req}) => ( return  /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/.test(value) )

Comment: doing this express validation works but .custom method not working